# Regular expression for a string of numbers

Tags: regex, bash, sed

Lets say I have a string of 4 numbers separated by space

```
1 4 16 28
# stored in $ids
```

So, to get the 4 number separately in four variables I was using

```
id1=$(echo $ids | sed -r "s/([0-9]+ ){0}([0-9]+) ?.*/\2/g")
id2=$(echo $ids | sed -r "s/([0-9]+ ){1}([0-9]+) ?.*/\2/g")
id3=$(echo $ids | sed -r "s/([0-9]+ ){2}([0-9]+) ?.*/\2/g")
id4=$(echo $ids | sed -r "s/([0-9]+ ){3}([0-9]+) ?.*/\2/g")
```

But the problem is, if the string has less then 4 numbers, the previous numbers are repeated.

For example, if the string was

```
1
```

then what we will get is

```
id1=1
id2=1
id3=1
id4=1
```

What I want is that, if there are less numbers, then the extra variables should have the value `0`.

Is there a way to do that?

**Note : I can only use sed**

Comment: Are you allowed to not use `sed` at all? that will give you a superior script, that will run faster! `IFS=' ' read -ra id_ary <<< "$ids"; for i in {0..3}; do [[ ${id_ary[i]} = +([[:digit:]]) ]] || id_ary[i]=0; done; id_ary=( "${id_ary[@]:0:3}" )`. At this point you have an array `id_ary` that contains the 4 wanted numbers (if a field is not a number then it is replaced by `0`).

Comment: Why only `sed`? when you can use native bash techniques to acheive this?

Comment: The problem is, the bash version my environment is running, is pretty simple and stripped down. Many features don't work, for example arrays.

Comment: What's your `BASH_VERSION`? Are you even using Bash at all?

Comment: Can't find out. The Cli doesn't have an option to find out the `BASH_VERSION`. Whichever command I have to use, I have to test it first whether it works or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex instead, it returns `""` if there is nothing to return:

```
$ echo 1 2 3 4 5 6|sed -r "s/^([0-9]+ *){0,3}//g;s/([0-9]+).*/\1/g;s/^$/0/g"
4
#                 change this latter value ^ 

$ echo 1 2 3|sed -r "s/^([0-9]+ *){0,3}//g;s/([0-9]+).*/\1/g;s/^$/0/g"
0
$
```

Comment: Yes, It does work. But `""` won't work for me. I have to later check for each variable and put `0` explicitly after this.

Comment: Well, add this to it: `;s/^$/0/g`. Edited in answer. It replaces `""` with `0`. Probably don't need the `g` in the end, either.

Comment: Thanks. It works. Can you please explain this a little.

Comment: The `s/^([0-9]+ *){1,3}//g` deletes up to 3 first instances, `s/([0-9]+).*/\1/g` returns the fourth and `s/^$/0/g` replaces `""` with a `0`, ie. if the fourth number doesn't exist, the returned empty is replaced by a `0`.

Comment: shouldn't it be `echo 1 2 3 4 | sed -r "s/^([0-9]+ *){0,0}//g;s/([0-9]+).*/\1/g;s/^$/0/g"` for the first number and so forth changing the latter number to `1, 2, 3`? I mean with `echo 1 2 3 4|sed -r "s/^([0-9]+ *){1,3}//g;s/([0-9]+).*/\1/g;s/^$/0/g"` how would we get the first number?

Comment: Can you please edit your answer so that I can accept your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

If you can use awk, you could try something like this:

```
$ awk 'function m(a) { return a ~ /^[0-9]+$/ ? a : 0 } 
  { print m($1), m($2), m($3), m($4) }'
1 4 16 281 # input
1 4 16 281
1          # input
1 0 0 0
```

The function tests whether the field contains one or more digits, replacing with `0` if it doesn't.

The best way to get the output into separate variables depends on what you plan on doing with them later and your shell version.

Using process substitution, you can do this:

```
str='1 4 16 281'
read -r id1 id2 id3 id4 < <(echo "$str" | awk '
  function m(a) { return a ~ /^[0-9]+$/ ? a : 0 } 
    { print m($1), m($2), m($3), m($4) }')
```

Less efficient but perhaps easier to understand would be to simplify the script and run it 4 times:

```
id1=$(echo "$str" | awk -v col=1 '{ print $col ~ /^[0-9]+$/ ? $col : 0 }')
```

Comment: I don't know `awk` properly. How am I suppose to use it. Is `a` the string variable?

Comment: @Haris I've updated to show a couple of ways to assign to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `sed`. This will work in any POSIX-compatible shell:

```
read -r id1 id2 id3 id4 rest <<EOF
$ids 0 0 0 0
EOF
```

This will work for any number of values in `ids`. The line in the here document will contain at least 4 values, regardless of the value of `ids`, and any extra fields will be assigned to `rest` and can be ignored.